# What is Python implicit relative import

Tags: python

In [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports
>
> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python3.

### What Is Python Implicit Relative Import?

Implicit import is a algorithm

> Search up from current package directory until the ultimate package parent gets hit.
> -- From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports

Can someone explain it in detail?

### Removed In Python3?

```
python2 -c 'import csv; print(csv)'
<module 'csv' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.pyc'>

$ touch csv.py

$ python2 -c 'import csv; print(csv)'
<module 'csv' from 'csv.pyc'>

# In python3 still search from current package
$ python3 -c 'import csv; print(csv)'
<module 'csv' from '/path_to/csv.py'>
```

### Why does pep-0008 suggest never use it?

Comment: what you quoted from the PEP8 is a suggested approach, that wasn't adopted

Answer (score 30):

When you say:

```
import foo
```

Python 2 would look first in the caller's directory.  Python 3 will not do that, and will only find `foo` in the usual places like `sys.path` (`PYTHONPATH`, `site-packages`, etc.).

This means if you're writing a package that supports Python 3, you should say this inside your package:

```
import mypkg.foo
```

Or use an explicit relative import:

```
from . import foo
```

Comment: This answer glosses over the fact that, when running a script, Python 3 can still resolve the import since the script directory is added to the "usual places" (it will be the first entry in `sys.path`).

Answer (score 4):

in python3, your code only works because python3 adds the parent directory of the python module you call to the sys.path

it won't work if you use submodule and use implicit relative import from submodule.

```
mkdir -p smod
touch smod/csv.py
echo 'import csv; print(csv)' > smod/__init__.py
python3 -c 'import smod; print(smod)'
<module 'csv' from '</path/to>/lib/python3.9/csv.py'>
<module 'smod' from '/<home>/test/smod/__init__.py'>
```