# Pypi package not getting installed

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm working on publishing a utility library for python, mostly for my own use. You can find it on pypi [here](https://pypi.org/project/raddoo/). Repository is [here](https://github.com/staab/raddoo). Here's my setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = raddoo
version = 0.0.4
description = "A collection of useful utility functions for python"

[options]
packages = raddoo
python_version = >=3.6
```

I'm building with `python -m build`, which gives me a tar.gz and whl file. When I `pipenv install raddoo` in another location, nothing appears to get installed into `site-packages`:

```
ls $(pipenv --venv)/lib/python3.9/site-packages
_distutils_hack              pip-21.3.1.virtualenv        setuptools-58.5.3.virtualenv
_virtualenv.pth              pkg_resources                wheel
_virtualenv.py               raddoo                       wheel-0.37.0.dist-info
distutils-precedence.pth     raddoo-0.0.4.dist-info       wheel-0.37.0.virtualenv
pip                          setuptools
pip-21.3.1.dist-info         setuptools-58.5.3.dist-info
```

Trying to import it fails as well:

```
python -c 'import raddoo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'raddoo'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you used ls, raddoo was there.

Make sure that the you are in your environment, and check the version of python.

Also, while trying to import it to test, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/raddoo/__init__.py", line 1
import .context
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To fix this, you can go into error.py, context.py, multimethod.py, and __init__.py and remove the periods in when you import, so instead of:

```
import .core
```

you would do:

```
import core
```

Comment: The dot definitely must be there else Python 3 wouldn't find the module (absolute vs relative import). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716965/7976758 and all answers at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+absolute+relative+import

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I was in the correct virtualenv, but the wrong directory, which made pipenv look in the wrong site-packages directory. I don't know why, but there you go.